# Logging in or Signing up as a customer just refreshes the page or redirects to 404 page

Tags: shopify

I'm having a problem with my shopify page: https://globaltravelclothing.com/account/login

Upon signing up or logging in as a customer, the page is only being refreshed or redirected to a 404 page. I'm not really sure what's wrong so if anyone can give me a lead on how to fix this I'll appreciate it very much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually occurs when accounts are disabled in your Shopify settings but links for them are live in your current theme.

To check if customer accounts are turned on, go to your Checkout settings page in your store's admin: https://globaltravelclothing.com/admin/settings/checkout#settings-customer-accounts

Make sure accounts are either optional or required - if they're set as disabled, attempts at logging in or registering will just go to a black hole.

Hope this helps!